How to center numbers in "alignedat" in LaTeX
When using alignedat to center numbers in equation.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
            a=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=&\frac{891}{1123}\\
            b=&\frac{\frac{456}{789}}{\frac{1011}{123}}&=&\frac{456}{789}\\
    \end{alignedat}
    \right\}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}


The   on the second line of the equation is left aligned. How to make it center?

Use an array for that instead. None of the amsmath envs are designed to center between aligmnets.

Maybe too much for the particular job, but IEEEeqnarraybox can be useful also in other situations. See Stefan Moser's manual for more details on IEEEeqnarray.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{rCcCl}
a &=& \frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}
           {\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}
  &=& \frac{891}{1123} \\[1ex]
b &=& \frac{\frac{456}{789}}{\frac{1011}{123}}
  &=& \frac{456}{789}\\
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}



IEEEtrantools is magic and very easy to use.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \left.\arraycolsep=1.5pt
    \begin{array}{rcl}
            a=&\dfrac{\dfrac{123 \sqrt{\dfrac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\dfrac{1011 \sqrt{\dfrac{12}{3}}}{4567}} &=\dfrac{891}{1123}\\
            ~\\
            b=&\dfrac{\dfrac{456}{789}}{\dfrac{1011}{123}} &= \dfrac{456}{789}\\
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{align}
\end{document}


